# What does the "existence" refer to at the end of the first surrealist manifesto?

Tags: literary-theory

> [This summer](http://wikilivres.ca/wiki/Surrealist_Manifesto) the roses are blue; the wood is of glass. The earth,
>   draped in its verdant cloak, makes as little impression upon me as a
>   ghost. It is living and ceasing to live which are imaginary solutions.
>   Existence is elsewhere.

What does the "existence" refer to at the end of the first surrealist manifesto?

I figured that the penultimate sentence is in praise of dreams as an "imaginary solution" to "life's problems": that when we dream we are alive but have stopped living (with life's problems). But I'm not sure, and that last sentence has me flummoxed.

**Is Breton saying that surrealist "automatism" does away with existence?** In what sense?

> SURREALISM, n. Psychic automatism in its pure state, by which one
>   proposes to express -- verbally, by means of the written word, or in
>   any other manner -- the actual functioning of thought. Dictated by the
>   thought, in the absence of any control exercised by reason, exempt
>   from any aesthetic or moral concern.

Comment: See the first paragraphs, with *imagination*. The conclusion stress the fact that "real life" is not in the ordinary world but in *imagination*, in the life of *unconscious*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA hm yeah, not sure but think that the question could have a more illuminating, in depth, answer, thanks for the note tho. e.g., it's meant to be a response to rimbaud's "real life is absent. we are not of this world"